# How access class hidden variables in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

unable to access      * @see #TYPE_BUILT_IN variable in Display class , but it showing in [Display class](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/Display.java) .How to access that variable , help me thanks in advance.

```
       DisplayManager manager = (DisplayManager) getSystemService(Context. DISPLAY_SERVICE);
   Display[] display = manager.getDisplays();

   // Display.DEFAULT_DISPLAY = 0; 
   // Display. TYPE_BUILT_IN = 1; 
   Presentation p = new Presentation(getApplicationContext(), display[Display.TYPE_BUILT_IN]);
```

Comment: What do you mean by unable to access ? Try to comment out your `Display.TYPE_BUILT_IN = 1;` line and tell us what is the error ?

Comment: un commented that it showing TYPE_BUILT_IN cannot be resolved or is not a field

Answer (score -1):

as public static final int TYPE_BUILT_IN = 1; use 1 value or use reflection.

Comment: Using reflection is really nasty here.. But if you want OP to do that make it easier for OP by sharing code example.

Comment: Tried reflection ,but its accessing only methods .. but trying to access variable.